# Auto sorting and Merging of the cells using vba in excel

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, merge

I have autosorted two of my rows using VBA in excel.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:D")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("C3").Sort Key1:=Range("C4"), _
          Order1:=xlAscending, _
          Key2:=Range("D4"), _
          Order2:=xlAscending, _
          Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=2, MatchCase:=False, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
End Sub
```

I have auto sorted column C and D in ascending order.

But when i merge 2 cells in Column J (i.e. J53 and J54) the auto sorting does not work for the Column C and D or the entire sheet we can say.

I want to merge the cells in Column J as well as make Column C and D auto sort using VBA.

NB: similarly i want to sort to 2 cells in Column K as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting does not work with merged cells. Except when all merged cells are the same size.

I highly recommend not to use `On Error Resume Next` without proper error handling. It just makes you blind to any errors but they still occur, you will just never know because the message is suppressed.

That is also why you didn't see the error message telling you exactly this! Remove `On Error Resume Next` and you will see the error message!

**Solution**
You can unmerge the cells to sort them, or use a 3ʳᵈ party tool like [Kutools: How To Sort Data With Merged Cells In Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3572-excel-sort-data-with-merged-cells.html)

Note that this is not the only case why merged cells are evil. Therefore I recommend not to use merged cells at all.

Comment: I agree that merged cells are evil!  Centre Across Selection formatting is better if you need some sort of heading.

Answer (score 0):

I would unmerge the cells, then sort and then merge again...